# Haskell - Return numbers in a given list greater than n

Tags: haskell

I have to create a function that receives a list of numbers and a number n, and it returns a list of all numbers greater than n. I want to use filter(>n) [x:xs] but I am unsure how to create that in a function foo.

Example: foo [1,2,3,4,5] 3 returns [4,5].

This is what I have but it isn't giving the correct output. I feel like it should be very simple.

```
foo n (x:xs)
| n x       = x : filter(>n) xs
| otherwise = foo f xs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
foo n xs = filter (> n) xs
```

or even

```
foo n = filter (> n)
```

(We could also go further and write `foo = filter . (<)` but I do not recommend it since we are approaching obfuscated code.)

Comment: I knew I was overthinking it. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing a `filter`-free definition (which mostly duplicates the definition of `filter`):

```
foo n [] = []
foo n (x:xs) | x > n     = x : foo n xs
             | otherwise =     foo n xs
```

with a thin wrapper around `filter`:

```
foo n xs = filter (> n) xs
-- foo n = filter (> n)
-- foo = filter . (<)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using fold function also.

```
foo n xs = foldl (\acc x-> if (x < n) then x:acc else acc) [] xs
```

This is not the best approach for this problem but it becomes handy some times.